# How can I properly reference the database link name in the below procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, dblink

I asked a similar question in another forum, but I didn't quite get the context correct so I've created a better example. Does anyone know how I can properly reference the link here? The code sends a .csv file to the related directory if you hard code the database link, but I want to pass it in a variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WRITE_EST_SIZE
IS
   file_handle   UTL_FILE.file_type;
   v_link_name   VARCHAR2 (10);
   v_csv_name    VARCHAR2 (40);
BEGIN
   v_csv_name := 'file_name';

   --Table contains the name of the database link
   SELECT link_name INTO v_link_name FROM link_name;

   file_handle :=
      UTL_FILE.fopen ('ESTIMATES_CSV',
                      v_csv_name || '.csv',
                      'w',
                      32767);
   UTL_FILE.put_line (file_handle,
                      'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,SEGMENT_TYPE,SUM_BYTES');

   FOR rws
      IN (  SELECT s.owner,
                   s.segment_name,
                   'T' AS FLAG,
                   SUM (s.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 AS SUM_BYTES
              FROM DBA_SEGMENTS@LINK_TO_DEV s
             --Actually, I want THIS below to work
             --from DBA_SEGMENTS@v_link_name s
             WHERE     s.owner =
                          (SELECT DISTINCT schema_name FROM target_schema)
                   AND s.segment_name IN (SELECT table_name FROM ref_table)
                   AND s.segment_type LIKE '%TABLE%'
          GROUP BY s.owner, s.segment_name)
   LOOP
      UTL_FILE.put_line (
         file_handle,
            rws.OWNER
         || ','
         || rws.SEGMENT_NAME
         || ','
         || rws.FLAG
         || ','
         || rws.SUM_BYTES);
   END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.fclose (file_handle);
END WRITE_EST_SIZE;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use dynamic SQL. If it was something *simple*, no problem about it, but - a *dynamic* cursor `FOR` loop? No, thank you.

Another option is to create a view as `UNION` of selects over all database links you might be using, e.g.

```
create or replace view v_dba_segments as
  select 'db_link_1' link, s.owner, s.segment_name, ...
  from dba_segments@db_link_1
  union all
  select 'db_link_2' link, s.owner, s.segment_name, ...
  from dba_segments@db_link_2
  union all 
  ...
```

Then you'd reference it in the above procedure as

```
for rws in (select owner, segment_name, ...
            from v_dba_segments             --> view
            where link = v_link_name        --> this is where your variable comes into the game
              and ...
           )
loop
   ...
end loop;
```

Comment: I took your advice on the view and created a view from the main SQL. 
    v_link := '(select link_name from link_name)';
    for rws in (
    'select * from '||v_link
    loop
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
    rws.OWNER || ',' ||
    rws.SEGMENT_NAME || ',' ||
    rws.FLAG || ',' ||
    rws.SUM_BYTES
    );
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
    end WRITE_EST_SIZE;

Comment: I'm struggling to explain because stackoverflow isn't allowing enough characters in a comment.

Comment: begin
v_link := '(select link_name from pdu.link_name)';                          And then later on:
for rws in '(select * from '(||v_link))

Comment: You got me wrong. Create a view. Then literally use code I wrote in "Then you'd reference it ..." - you should **NOT** have anything *dynamic* afterwards. `v_link_name` is its "alias", the `link` column value in `v_dba_segments` view.